# Performance testing of Dockerized application hosted on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, performance-testing

Our project involves containerisation of services / application and later they will be deployed on Kuberentes. My job is to do performance testing using Jmeter after the services are hosted on Kubernetes.

I am relatively new to Performance testing and have basic experience on Jmeter that I gained from working on it. I have understood how the app is load / perf tested using basic URLs or APIs but I want to know how I should go about handling performance testing for Docker containers hosted on Kubernetes.

How could I handle the above scenario?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately our ranked Q&A format is not a good fit for these kinds of open ended questions that don’t have a specific answer. I would recommend seeking a mentor inside your company or your local DevOps community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter doesn't know anything about the underlying technologies used at the backend, it just sends requests via [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), waits for responses and measures the elapsed time of the request and some other [performance metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites). Later on you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) to visualize the results

So your goal is to:

1. Identify the [business use cases](https://sceweb.uhcl.edu/helm/RationalUnifiedProcess/process/modguide/md_bucm.htm) you need to implement for the performance testing
2. Identify [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) which are being used under the hood of these business use cases
3. Create a JMeter [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) to precisely mimic the real user (or other application) accessing your system and doing what it supposed to be doing